# How to show a view from scrollview

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a view that contains a ScrollView opening two xibs.
There is a button on a Xib contained in ScrollView.
I want that after clicking the button, open a new view outside of the ScrollView.
But I can not open a new view outside the Scrollview. = /

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

present the view modally or in the root view.  From your UIViewController, call `[self.view.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:newController animated:YES]` or `[self.view.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:newView]'.